# Trying to parse multiple values in cell, data type string and return the highest value

Tags: google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to read through all cells in column **C** and only return the highest value, this can be put into a different cell or overwrite that cell.  The problem is the data looks like this and the only thing constant are

- there is a `;` delimiter
- there are characters and a space before the numbers

  'Sprint 17; DD 13; DD 18; AB 18; DD 11'

In the above example, I only care about 18, I don't care about which 18.

The dataset is only about 200 rows, so I don't care too much about performance.  The page gets refreshed frequently so I need to run the scripts as a macro after each refresh unless there is a better way.

I'm not a coder, but work with some c# guys that should be able to help me translate any answers if needed.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
=MAX(SPLIT(A1, "; "))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

This is common formula:

```
=array_constrain(SORT(filter(transpose(SPLIT(A118, "; ")) ,isnumber(transpose(SPLIT(A118, "; ")))=BooleanNumber),1,BooleanAsc),1,1)
```

So, for number and max:

```
=array_constrain(SORT(filter(transpose(SPLIT(A118, "; ")) ,isnumber(transpose(SPLIT(A118, "; ")))=True),1,False),1,1)
```

and for string and min:

```
=array_constrain(SORT(filter(transpose(SPLIT(A118, "; ")) ,isnumber(transpose(SPLIT(A118, "; ")))=False),1,True),1,1)
```

And for number only, the easy way is use as @player0 formula